# How does this formula work?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I came across this formula which works out the date Easter falls on in any given year, but for the life of me I can't figure out how it works!

Can any body shed some light on what it's various components are doing?

```
=DOLLAR(("4/"&A1)/7+MOD(19*MOD(A1,19)-7,30)*14%,)*7-6
```

The formula assumes cell A1 has a year in it.

Comment: Well one thing I can tell you is that the result is a raw [OLE date](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tooadate(v=vs.110).aspx#Remarks). However, I have no idea what the “divide string by number” part does. // Got it: The string is interpreted as a date (which is, again, an OLE date number).

Comment: [Easter Dating Method](https://www.assa.org.au/edm), and [Computus software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computus#Software)

Comment: It is implementing one of the many [algorithms for calculating the date of easter](http://www.cantab.net/users/michael.behrend/algorithms/easter/pages/main.html)

Comment: I googled search and came up with this: http://www.contextures.com/exceleastercalculation.html. Links could get you to original posting. The second place seems to be the formula you have.

Answer (score -1):

=DOLLAR - is a function that converts the following number into current currency (i suspect from country you are or your account is)

**MOD(dividend;divider)** - is a value that is returned after your **"dividend"** was divided with "**divider"** for example:

5 divide 2 you have 1 is left undivided
and
4 divide 2 you have 0 left undivided

then goes: (4 / "value in cell A1") / 7+ 
  MOD(19[dividend]MOD(value in A1[dividend], 19[divider])-7,30[divider])
and this returned number is multiplied by * 14%,)

after all calculations the value is multiplied x 7
and is substructed by -6 in the end

I think that was helpfull, because i am not very good in such english explanations. =)

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't actually explain why the formula works - how do these calculations result in the date for Easter?

Comment: Can any body shed some light on what it's various components are doing?

you got answer =)

I think you should see what =DOLLAR is doing, because it can be very different for every account

Comment: interesting function. I want to work it out. In reference to the =DOLLAR(value,) acts like =ROUND(value,0)